# Getting current view from ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I'm trying to get current page view from ViewPager with **Viewpager.findViewWithTag**. When try to get current view from ViewPager it returns Null;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.viewpager_main);
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    chapter = bundle.getInt("chapter");


    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(this, chapter);
    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);

    View myView = pager.findViewWithTag(pager.getCurrentItem());
```

... and here's my ViewPageAdapter

```
 @Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    if(position != 10){
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
     itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewpager_item, container,
            false);
      itemView.setTag(position);

    } else {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
         itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.results, container,
                false);
    }
    container.addView(itemView);
    return itemView ;
}
```

Here's viewpager_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and here's viewpager_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:tag="1"
        android:text="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:tag="2"
        android:text="2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:tag="3"
        android:text="3" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:tag="4"
        android:text="4" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:tag="5"
        android:text="5" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I don't know where did i do a mistake but couldn't fix it. Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to fetch the child views of the ViewPager or the items of the ViewPager ?

Comment: I'm trying get Buttons from it;

Comment: Can you please post your xml where your ViewPager is ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can try something like this -

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    if(position != 10){
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
     itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewpager_item, container,
            false);
      itemView.setTag("View"+position);

    } else {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
         itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.results, container,
                false);
    }
    container.addView(itemView);
    return itemView ;
}
```

And when you need the current view-

```
View myView = pager.findViewWithTag("View"+pager.getCurrentItem());
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue here is that you are calling pager.getCurrentItem() right after setting the PagerAdapter via

```
pager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The page is not necessarily created immediately. That is PageAdapter.instantiateItem is called after your call to

```
View myView = pager.findViewWithTag(pager.getCurrentItem());
```

If you need the view right after it is created, just do what you need to do in the Adapter, otherwise your call should work if called in a listener such as OnPageChangeListener.onPageSelected.